# Confusion in MicroTask Queue and MacroTask Queue

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in JS and While going through `Event Loop and Promises`, I came across the below example at `mdn`.

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

wait().then(() => console.log(4));
Promise.resolve().then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));
console.log(1); // 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Shouldn't the O/P be `1,4,2,3`?

These are the steps, which according to my understanding should have happened

1. setTimeout CB in MacroTask Q
2. log(4) CB in MicroTask Q
3. log(2) CB in MicroTask Q
4. log(3) CB in MicroTask Q

log(1) and then empty the MicroTask Q in the FIFO order.
What am I getting wrong here, please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wait` function's promise resolves only after the `setTimeout` finishes - after a macrotask (a few milliseconds) In contrast, the `Promise.resolve` gets put onto the microtask queue, which will run first (often a millisecond or less). After the `console.log(1)` line runs, you'll have the following:

Microtask queue: `.then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3));`

Macrotask queue: `resolve` (due to the `setTimeout`)

Microtask queue runs first, so `2` gets logged, then the next `.then` gets put onto the microtask queue, and `3` gets logged. Finally, the `setTimeout` macrotask runs, resolving the `wait` Promise, putting another `.then` onto the microtask queue, and shortly causing `4` to be logged.

Comment: Shouldn't the MacoTask run first since it has a CB? and then all the MicroTasks? According to below mdn

1.Check if there is any task available in the macrotasks queue.
2.If so and this task is running, wait until it is completed before going to the next step. If not, go directly to step 3.
3.Then run all the microtasks that are in the microtask queue.

Comment: The microtask queue must be empty before any macrotask runs. Microtasks, then macrotasks.